# Complex LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
These are my two tables. How can i make LINQ query between two tables :

(1) Users : 
       Id , Name, Email
(2) Articles : 
       Id,Title, Description ,UserId (Foreign key reference to User Table Id column)

Questions :

(1)  How to select all records that are similar in both tables ? (Inner Join)
(2)  Left Join (Only record of left table)
(3)  Right Join (Only record of right table)
(4)  Full outer join (All records of both tables)
```

Please provide me help in creating LINQ query with joins as i am a beginner in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Downvoter provide me reason

Comment: Am i missing something in explanation ?? Let me know without downvoting..

Comment: Why anybody down vote without any reason ? I am still surprising .. :(

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but this sounds more like an assignment than a question. A question is usually better asked with a concrete example in mind than asking for a tutorial.

Comment: This is real life program and i am stuck since morning :(. Dont have much knowledge in using LINQ.

Comment: Have you checked MSDN samples, such as these?  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: You create navigation properties on your data types and forget about the joins.

Comment: Gh9 already provided me with correct answer. Yet some people are downvoting without any reason

Comment: Why anybody down vote without any reason ? I am still surprising .. :( –

Comment: To put my previous comment more constructively and less bluntly: downvoted for 1) not showing research effort; 2) four questions that should probably be separated; 3) looks like an assignment; 4) contains text other than code within the `code` block. Also note that it's not mandatory for anyone to justify their downvotes. Please keep these in mind for your future questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Below is all pseudo code and you will need to adapt per your tablenames and needs**.

```
 var question_one = (from u in Users
                        join a in Articles on u.Id equals a.UserId)

var question_two = (from u in user
                    join a in Articles on u.Id equals a.UserId into leftJoin
                    from subUser in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select subUser)

var question_three = (from a in Articles
                    join  u in user  on a.UserId equals u.Id  into leftJoin
                    from subUser in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select subUser)
```

Question Four cannot be done in a conventional outer join because, articles table is really a child table of users. Therefore any article is guaranteed to always have a user. What you can do is just materilize your User table and include any articles like so

WARNING PSEUDO CODE AS I DO NOT KNOW YOUR NAVIGATION PROPERTIES

```
Users.include(x => x.Articles).ToList();
```

[msdn for linq joining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: You are great. Thanks for your help :)